# Convert String to SqlDbType

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am trying to convert a string values into a SqlDbType. My code is able to covert "Text" into SqlDbType.Text without any errors  but when I try to convert "bit" into SqlDbType.Bit, I receive the following error: **"Requested value 'bit' was not found."**

The same thing happens when trying to convert "int" into SqlDbType.Int Error Message: **"Requested value 'int' was not found."**

Why will this work for "text" but not "bit" or "int"?

```
Dim MyType as String = "bit"
Dim sdtype As SqlDbType

sdtype = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(SqlDbType), MyType), SqlDbType)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because the enum value is SqlDbType.Bit, not SqlDbType.bit. Enum.Parse() is case-sensitive WRT to its input.

You need to use this overload of Enum.Parse:

```
SqlDbType type = (SqlDbType) Enum.Parse( typeof(SqlDbType) , "bit" , true ) ;
```

The third parameter indicates whether (true) or not (false) case should be ignored in parsing the enum's value from a string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's case-sensitive. Try "Bit" and see if that works out.

Comment: You are right. I just notice there is a flag that will ignore case. I added True and it works! sdtype = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(SqlDbType), MyType), SqlDbType, True)

Answer (score 0):

What is the result of [Enum].Parse(GetType(SqlDbType))? Is this the result you expect? Because I think the error might be in there.

As a last alternative, could you try CTYpe instead if direct cast? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x(VS.71).aspx)

CType is slightly more flexible, however I do think it is a long shot, but maybe worth trying.